# 'mongo' is still not working on PowerShell after doing all recommended things

Tags: database, mongodb

I installed **MongoDB** and tried to run it on **terminal**. It just shows up *`'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`*.
I have set the path to **bin** folder inside **Environment variables** too. One thing I noticed is I might have a missing *file* inside **bin folder** and that is *mongo*. Because I have *mongod* and *mongos* file inside the bin folder. I tried to **uninstall** and **reinstall** the program and it was still not working.
I have no idea it's what that I'm missing. Please help out

Comment: You didn't specify what system you were on. Could be important if you're trying to use linux version (judging by mongod, a daemon file) on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution,
Mongo shell no longer ships with server binaries. We can download it from [MongoDB Shell Download](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

Then we should *extract the contents of the bin* from the **downloaded zip file** to the **bin file of the MongoDB folder** and run mongosh instead of mongo on the terminal